# VBScript will only save a Copy of my file

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have written a small script that opens an excel workbook, executes a macro, and then saves the workbook.  The only problem is that after the macro executes, the save prompt asks if I want to save a copy of my file, not the file itself.  If I click on the original file and override the copy save, the prompt just pops up again and asks me to save a copy, without having changed my original file. Does anyone know how to fix this??

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HGAGNE\Desktop\Master.xlsm", 0, False)
xlApp.Run "BatchProcessing"
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True


Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: What does the "save" line in your `BatchProcessing` macro look like?  Something like `Activeworkbook.Save` or `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code (as shown) does not attempt to save or close the open workbook; neither does it attempt to quit the Excel.Application before destroying the object. On a related matter, the second parameter of the [Workbooks.Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195811(v=office.11).aspx) (e.g. *UpdateLinks*) does not take 0 as an accepted value.

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
'set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HGAGNE\Desktop\Master.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=2, ReadOnly:=False)'in VBA as this for explanation
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HGAGNE\Desktop\Master.xlsm", 2, False)                       'in VBS

xlApp.Run "BatchProcessing"

'xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=True  'in VBA as this for explanation
xlBook.Close True                'in VBS
xlApp.Quit

'xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True  'not really a need for this

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

That code was tested as a sub in in an MS Access VBA project and as a VBS script file.